# how to request focus on the second editText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

i want focus in the second editText ,also can make edit in the first

I have two edit text , i tried to put in the second edittext

```
        android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

but when tested it still focus in the firstEdit text

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1Price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

</EditText>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2Funds"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:inputType="number"        
     />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this may little help you !
try this in your **`.java`** file :

```
EditText edittxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2Funds);

edittxt.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 5):

Keep **`<requestFocus/>`** in the Second `EditText`.

Comment: I try this not working
,,
where exactly put <requestFocus/> ?

Answer (score 4):

try this,you have to add below code in which edittext you show focus..

```
 <EditText...>
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
```